While setting background Image to linear layout using glide, it appears stretched
How to preserve aspect ratio/scale of image while trying to set it as background image to LinearLayout in Android using Glide?
Hi there, I am new to Android developement.
What I want to achieve is this:
I have a Linear Layout component and I want to set an image covering one-third of the background and two-thirds with a solid color.
Problem:
the image I am passing already has width as one-third of linearLayout width, but using the below code makes it stretch in the entire available width of linearLayout and the color layer comes on top of it in two-third to area. I want the image to maintain its original aspect ratio/scale (if they are the correct terms to be used here. apologies, in case they are incorrect.)
Code:
presenter.kt
val linearLayout = findViewByid(R.id.myLinearLayout)

Glide.with(linearLayout.context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(R.drawable.backgroundimage)
    .into(
       object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource : Bitmap, transition: Transition<? super Bitmap>?) {
              val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.GREY)      
              val imageDrawable = Bitmap(resource)
              val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf(imageDrawable, colorDrawable))
              layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, linearLayout.width / 3, 0, 0 , 0)
              linearLayout.setBackground(resource);
            }
        });

layout.xml
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

I have also tried some hacks I found in google like:

using .dontTransform() while loading image on Glide
imageDrawable.setBounds(0,0,resource.width, resource.heigth)
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, resource.widt, 0, 0 , 0)
setting LinearLayout height to zero

Nothing worked out.
Will appreciate any help or directions. Thanks in advance.

why are you putting an image in a linearlayout? you dont have any control over your image, you should be using an ImageView and laying it ontop of the linearlayout or something

Apologies, this was the first time I posted any question and its poorly defined. So basically i wanted to set an image with some color in the background of linearlayout. I figured out that i should create two different views - an image view and another view of color inside linear layout. And That resolved my issue.
